# OsError(err) in PIL Image library using Image.paste

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am doing a small script to paste an image into a black background to have same size images for a dataset. Here is the script:

```
for file in glob.glob(imagetteDir):
    r = str(file)
    image = Image.open(file)
    img = np.zeros([100,100,3],dtype=np.uint8) 
    imageio.imwrite('black.tif', img)
    black = Image.open('black.tif')
    position = ((black.width - image.width), (black.height - image.height))
    print(position)

    Image.Image.paste(black,image,position)

    dirr , name = r.split("imagette")
    path1 = name.raplace("Hexagone_resized","Hexagone")
    print(path1)
    black.save(imagetteresizeDir+path1)
```

So Image.Image.paste() make the following error that i didnt find how to resolve:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\user\Documents\Project\segmentation\Imagette creation\resizing.py", line 29, in <module>
    Image.Image.paste(black,image)

  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\envs\tf_gpu\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 1455, in paste
    im.load()

  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\envs\tf_gpu\lib\site-packages\PIL\TiffImagePlugin.py", line 1070, in load
    return self._load_libtiff()

  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\envs\tf_gpu\lib\site-packages\PIL\TiffImagePlugin.py", line 1182, in _load_libtiff
    raise OSError(err)

OSError: -2
```

Have you any idea from where it might come?

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: It seems that the TIFF library required by the TIFF plugin `TiffImagePlugin.py` is not found.

Comment: You can try to set `DEBUG=True` in the `"C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\envs\tf_gpu\lib\site-packages\PIL\TiffImagePlugin.py"` file to have more clue on where the code is going.

Comment: Read up on [`Image.paste(im, box=None, mask=None)`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.paste). The second argument have to be the box. You are using the `class definition` instead of the `class instance`.

Comment: @stovfl While it did not solve the issue, it seems "https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pil-paste-and-rotate-method/" is not consistent with the right documentation so i got wrong. Thanks for putting out. I tried doing it by hand on the matrice with .load of numpy and it makes the same error. I found this related issue : https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/4237